# About Formatting Fonts in Dev C++

Tags: formatting, indentation, dev-c++

I don't know How to change font formatting in Dev C++, BTW This is my first time use of Dev-C++ . You can found it in below.

[image: It's Look Like That]

Answer (score 3):

Go to tools > Editor Options > Fonts